# Combination of n sets of m elements

Tags: statistics, combinations

I have n sets and I want calculate all the combination such that there is just an element of every set in each combination.

How can I express this in a combination forumula?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is meant by a "combination"? Secondly: are the $n$ sets disjoint?

Comment: Disjoint sets with different cardinality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bullet$ **For sets of the same cardinality:**

Let ${m_1, m_2, ..., m_n}$ be your $n$ sets of $m$ elements each.

We want to pick one of $m$ elements, for every set $m_i$, where $ 1 \le i \le n$. Then there are $m$ possibilities for the first set, m possibilities for the second set, and so on. We can express this as
$$\underbrace{ m \times m \times m \times \cdots \times m}_{\text{n times}}$$
or
$$ m^n$$

Hence, there are $m^n$ possible combinations satisfying the given condition.

$\bullet$ **For sets of different cardinality:**

The approach is similar, just as stated by @drhab:

> If set $i$ has cardinality $m_i$ then there are $m_1$ possibilities for the first set, $m_2$ for the second, et cetera. That results in 
>   $m_1 \times m_2 \times \cdots \times m_n$ possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I commited a mistake. The sets can have different cardinality. How can I consider this?

Comment: @NxA In the line of this answer: if set $i$ has cardinality $m_i$ then there are $m_1$ possibilities for the first set, $m_2$ for the second, et cetera. That results in $m_1\times m_2\times\cdots\times m_n$ possibilities.

Comment: I would add the content of @drhab's comment into your answer (attributed, of course), because comments can be deleted without history, but answer edits are retained.